# Regex which should not allow any special characters except ,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a regular expression which does not allow any special characters except `,`, `.` and they should not come side by side.

For example: `STax.sdn,skm` should be accepted whereas `SDs,.Hnj` should throw an error message. I have used the below code, however it is accepting `,` and `.` side by side which I don't want.

```
function validateAnnouncementTags(){
  var announcementTags = document.getElementById("announcementTags").value;
  if (announcementTags.search(/[<>'+\"\/`\\\[\]^={}%;@#!$&*()?:|]/)>-1 ) {
    $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('hide');
    $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').removeClass('show');
  }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be easier to invert the logic and specify the characters that *are* allowed

Comment: do a seprate search for ,. being together

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can I write the other logic? Because except the above logic if I used other logic then it is not accepting anything.

Comment: That would depend on what the valid characters are; which you haven't yet stated in the question

Comment: it can accept all Alphanumeric characters except special characters excluding . and ,

Comment: for eg : It can accept SDV.SG,KJ but it should not accept VGF.,HJK

Comment: string `indexOf` method: Why not use this method?

Comment: I have changed the regEx as /^[a-z0-9]+([,.][a-z0-9]+)*$/ which is working for me.. Thanks @RoryMcCrossan , VIPER for the suggestions

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern:

```
/^(?!.*[\.,])/
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I am assuming that you want to accept any letters separated by periods or commas. How about we:

1. Check for valid characters, and
2. Ensure that no "special" chars occur adjacent?

we can use

```
function validateAnnouncementTags() {
   var announcementTags=document.getElementById("announcementTags").value;

   if (announcementTags.match(/[a-zA-Z\.,]*/)[0] != annoucementTags
       || announcementTags.search(/[\.,][\.,]/) >= 0 
      ) {
      $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('show');
   } else {
      $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('hide');
      $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').removeClass('show');
   }
}
```

But, if I may be so bold as to assume more structure to your acceptable syntax:

1. Accept any sequence of letters separated by a comma or period
2. The sequence will not start with a comma or period
3. The sequence can end with a comma or period

Then we can use:

```
function validateAnnouncementTags() {
   var announcementTags=document.getElementById("announcementTags").value;

   if (announcementTags.match(/([a-z0-9]+[\.,]?)*/)[0] != annoucementTags ) {
      $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('show');
   } else {
      $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('hide');
      $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').removeClass('show');
   }
}
```

Comment: function validateAnnouncementTags(){
 
 var announcementTags = document.getElementById("announcementTags").value;
 var regex1 = /^[a-z0-9]+([,.][a-z0-9]+)*$/;
 
  if (announcementTags.search(/^[a-z0-9]+([,.][a-z0-9]+)*$/)>-1) {
    $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('hide');
      $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').removeClass('show');
         
      }
      else {
       $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('show');
          $('#announcementTagsSpecialCharError').addClass('hide');
       
      }
}

Comment: Yes, that can work, though it assumes more than I did, relative to your original question :-) Be sure to escape the period in your regex. Did my answer lead your to your answer? If so, would you mind accepting my answer?